# Android spinner crashing application

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a android spinner to select among city names.
The problem is that the line where I setAdapter() is crashing my application.

`

```
   selectCity = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectCity);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(main.this, R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
            spinadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        selectCity.setAdapter(spinadapter);`

selectCity.setAdapter(spinadapter);// line is throwing a java.lang.nullpointerexception.
```

I also tried using array adapter constructor and using that but same problem.

Comment: it probably means `selectCity` is `null`. make sure that spinner with id `spinnerSelectCity` is present in layout and that you call `findViewById` after setting content view.

Comment: Yes As Vladimir said select city is null.Either put try catch and debug you will come to know that what is the problem.If you solved accept Prasham answer

Comment: Ok guys I got my mistake.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968573/android-viewpager-findviewbyid-not-working-always-returning-null
The above solution solved my issue.
Sorry for bothering you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectCity` is null....

Check the xml you use as view, does it have any spinner whose ID is  `spinnerSelectCity`?

if not

1. Replace the layout which is having `spinnerSelectCity` in it
2. You may have used it in another layout that will not be on use..... move `spinnerSelectCity`from that layout to the layout you use...

Comment: I think I have a broblem as I am using ViewPager to swipe between views contained in xml files.I tried following steps outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968573/android-viewpager-findviewbyid-not-working-always-returning-null
as I have a pretty similar setup but its still returning null.

Comment: Can you guide as to how I should overcome the problem.Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Ok guys I got my mistake.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968573/android-viewpager-findviewbyid-not-working-always-returning-null
The above solution solved my issue.
Sorry for bothering you guys.